# Co-adjoint orbit

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, symplectic-geometry

I just started to learn about the slice theorem in symplectic geometry, but I get stuck in understanding this paragraph:

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group with Lie algebra  $\mathfrak{g}$ and let $\mathcal{O}$ be a co-adjoint orbit of $\mathfrak{g}^*$.
Let T be a maximal torus of $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{t}$, and let $W$ be the Weyl group associated. We make a choice of a Weyl chambers $\mathfrak{t}_+^*$ in $\mathfrak{t}^*$. Let $\xi$ be the unique point in $\mathfrak{t}_+^*$ such that $\mathcal{O} = G. \xi$, and let $\sigma$ be the unique open face of $\mathfrak{t}_+^*$ which contains $\xi$. The stabilizer subgroup $G^{\xi'} \subset G $ doesn't depend on the choice of $\xi' \in \sigma$, and is denoted $G_\sigma$.

My questions are the following:

> Let $\xi$ be the unique point in $\mathfrak{t}_+^*$ such that $\mathcal{O} = G. \xi$

Why it's guaranteed that there is a unique element $\xi$ in $\mathfrak{t}_+^*$ which satisfies $\mathcal{O} = G. \xi$ ?

> The stabilizer subgroup $G^{\xi'} \subset G $ doesn't depend on the choice of $\xi' \in \sigma.$

Why this is true ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Ad{Ad}$The fact about "independence" of the stabiliser group of the representative is actually a fact about conjugacy; if $\xi, \xi' \in \sigma$, then there is $g_0 \in G$ so that $\xi' = \Ad(g_0)\xi$, and then $G_{\xi'} = \{g \in G \mathrel: \Ad(g g_0)\xi = \Ad(g_0)\xi\} = \{g \in G \mathrel: \Ad(g_0^{-1}g g_0)\xi = \xi\} = g_0 G_\xi g_0^{-1}$.

The fact about all elements of the torus being conjugate into a chosen chamber is not elementary, but is standard, and should be in any compact-Lie-group textbook.  Since you said on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394733/coadjoint-orbits#comment1010043_394733) that you are learning from [Sepanski - Compact Lie groups](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-49158-5), I cite the relevant results there, which are Theorems 5.9 and 6.43(c).

Comment: I don't want to bother you by asking for more details, but I'll read your answer very  carefully with the theorems in Sepanski's book and your comments in MO to get a better understanding! Thank you very much for taking the time to help me!

Comment: My pleasure, and no bother if you do ask.  The representation and structure theory of compact Lie groups is about as beautiful a theory as you can get—its only deficit being that it's essentially "[closed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347540/what-are-examples-of-collections-of-papers-which-close-a-field/347580#347580)"—so you're definitely in for a treat as you learn it.

Comment: Thank you @LSpice! I'm just wondering wether  the stabilizers $G^\xi $ and $G^{\xi'}$ are equal for every $\xi$ and $\xi'$ in the same Weyl chamber or we have to require that $\xi$ and $\xi'$ lie in the same open face to get the equality of their stabilizer groups ?

Comment: If you  permit me I just want to ask you also to suggest me some good easy reference(s) , from wich I can  learn in short time about representation of compact Lie group ( I'm PhD in the last year (actually last months) and I need to learn about Compact Lie groups in a short time in order to get some results in my thesis).

Comment: $G^\xi$ and $G^{\xi'}$ are definitely *not* isomorphic if $\xi$ and $\xi'$ lie in different-dimensional faces; the dimension of the face tells you (though it's not the same as) the dimension of $G^\xi$.  (Of course, conjugate faces give rise to conjugate stabilisers.)  For $\xi$ and $\xi'$ in the same open face, the groups are actually equal.  (This is a characteristic-$0$ phenomenon; centralisers even of ss Lie-algebra elements may be disconnected in small positive characteristic.)

Comment: I thought I remembered learning about compact groups from a Séminaire Bourbaki article by Serre, but I can't find it now.  Simon's [Representations of finite and compact groups](https://doi.org/10.1038/383266a0) is far from perfect, but it may be a good choice for a quick learning guide and reference.

Comment: By the way, if you find this answer satisfactory, you may decide to close your [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394733/coadjoint-orbits).

Comment: thank you very much @LSpice for your answer about the stabilizers of elements in the same face, now it's much clear for me, and thank you for the references I'll use them to learn more. Have a nice day !